# What is the Maximum scale a cube could be at and still be rotated at any angle to fit within a cube 1x1x1 units

Tags: geometry

so say I have 2 cubes A and B
what is the maximum size cube A while able to be rotated at any angle and still fit in cube B which is 1 unit cubed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [[A]] Draw a Square , then a Circle inside that & then a Square inside that : We can see that the Inner Square can be $1/\sqrt{2}$ at the maximum. [[B]] Moving to a Cube containing a Sphere containing a Cube : We might know that the Inner Cube can be $1/\sqrt{3}$ at the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Rotating A at any angle traces out a sphere of diameter $d$ equal to the cube's diagonal $\ell_A\sqrt{3}$. This sphere should fit within cube B, i.e. be inscribed in it, thus $d=\ell_B$. This implies $\ell_A=\ell_B/\sqrt{3}$

Answer (score 1):

To freely rotate shape A inside of shape B, what we want is for the "surface" sphere obtained from the combined volumes of all rotations of shape A to match up with the negative "inside" sphere combined from all rotations of a hollow shape B. These spheres will have the radius of the furthest outward and closest inward points respectively.

The closest points of a cube to its center describes a sphere which we can use to fill the inside of cube B. If cube B is $1\text{u}^3$, then the radius of sphere B is $r_B = 0.5\text{u}$.

[image: cube of size 1 with inner sphere of size 1]

The furthest points of a cube from its center allows us to describe a sphere to bound the outside of cube A.

[image: cube of size 1 with outer sphere of size root(3)]

If cube A has an edge length of $S \text{u}$, then the distance between the furthest vertices of the cube can be obtained via the Pythagorean Theorem, as the edges of a cube form $90\deg$ angles. This length is the diameter of our sphere, with the radius being half as much:

$$r_A = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{S^2 + S^2 + S^2}$$

To maximize the size of cube A, this sphere must have the same radius as cube B. Solve via the following:

\begin{align}
r_B &= r_A \\
0.5\text{u} &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{S^2 + S^2 + S^2} \\
1\text{u} &= \sqrt{S^2 + S^2 + S^2} \\
1\text{u}^2 &= S^2 + S^2 + S^2 \\
&= 3S^2 \\
\frac{1}{3}\text{u}^2 &= S^2 \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\text{u} &= S
\end{align}

Our inner cube must have an edge length of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\text{u}$, which is a volume of $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}\text{u}^3$.